# Questions about ModelViewPreseneter pattern

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, mvp

Lately I've been studying mvp design pattern and have some questions about it:

1. I've read that it's recommended to not use this design in simple applications. So I'd like to know when an application can be marked as "simple"?:

   a) Based on what we meassure coplexity of an application?

   b) How can we be sure that developed application will be still simple in the future (Especially due to the agile development when the application can grow unpredictably)
2. Should business logic sit in the presenter? Or business logic should be a concern/responsibility of a different part of a solution?
3. Is model something that is also implemented (module, class) or it's only an abstraction for a real world data storage (DB, disk) we get data from?

Answer (score 0):

1. MVC is a standard pattern used in most technologies out the box, in .net as an example it would be hard to get away from using MVC. In my opinion all applications should be built with some framework at it's core this one of those thing to always implement.
2. Most applications (bottom up stack) are the Database / Data Access (Models/Business Logic) / Controllers / Presentation
   The Presentation could be anything, mobile app, website, integrated app and should interact with an API (or controllers) that should be as light weight as possible that call the data/access or logic beneath.
3. The term models can use for various things but there are two main areas where "models" are  found, the models that represent data related to data access, ie models that represent tables or stored objects used in the data access side or models that are used on the front end to present specific data based on views/behaviour on the front end; ViewModels or Models (DTO objects) exposed via the API/controllers.